# Coloring categorical scatter plot by y-value groups

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using seaborn's `stripplot()` to plotting categorical data. As an example, I have two categories and two sets of y coordinates. How can I color the points according to their y grouping rather than the categories?

Here's an example with random data:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.array([['Category 1']*25, ['Category 2']*25])
x.shape = (-1,)
y1 = np.random.rand(50)
y2 = np.random.rand(50)
sns.stripplot(x, y1, label='A')
sns.stripplot(x, y2, label='B')
plt.savefig('scatter.png')
```

This colors the points by their category. Instead, I want all of the points in `y1` to be the same and all the points in `y2` to be the same.

Comment: This sounds too trivial to be asked about, so I might not understand it correctly; but to color a stripplot uniform use `color="red"` or whatever you need.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks. I was definitely making it more complex than necessary.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Can you post that as an answer? I know it is pretty trivial, but it might be helpful to someone in the future.